# Unable to poison DNS with `dnsmasq`

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

In my Tomato router, I added `address=/example.com/192.168.1.200` to my `dnsmasq.conf` so that https://example.com in my browser works even if the internet is down.

After adding it, `ping example.com` would should 192.168.1.200 on my router which is what I expected.

However, I can't `ping example.com` from my Windows 10, it gives the error `Ping request could not find host example.com. Please check the name and try again.`

I also tried a simpler method, which is to add `192.168.1.200 example.com` to `/etc/hosts`. It also caused Windows to have the same `...could not find host...`

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to use `Static DHCP` to achieve what I wanted by putting `example.com` under hostname, and the LAN IP address that it was hosted at.

Yes, it meant having multiple entries with the same IP address. For some reason, it worked (without having to flush any DNS cache on any clients).

Answer (score 0):

Clear the dns cache with `Clear-DnsClientCache` in powershell or with `ipconfig /flushdns` in CMD. You need to run them with Administrator priviledges. Or reboot the windows machine. Make sure you are using your router DNS with `Get-DnsClientServerAddress`

Comment: Pardon me but every other client of mine had the same issue including mac, so while it sounds logical, flushing is the equivalent of tech support asking to reboot the machine and see if it helps.